# replacing NaN in dataframe trucates digits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand why replacing NaN by whitespaces reduces the number of displaying digits.

I have the DataFrame:

```
0    -3.030889       -3.510211       -3.502291       -3.502357       -3.502817
1    -3.460590             NaN       -3.584687             NaN             NaN
2    -2.151932       -2.504276       -2.494087       -2.493053       -2.493741
3    -2.462477             NaN       -2.556205             NaN             NaN
4    -1.712807       -1.906281       -1.902953       -1.902297       -1.902253
5    -1.883432             NaN       -1.932924             NaN             NaN
```

After using `df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) some numbers are displayed with 5 decimal digits.

```
0    -3.030889       -3.51021       -3.502291       -3.50236       -3.50282
1    -3.460590                      -3.584687                                                        
2    -2.151932       -2.50428       -2.494087       -2.49305       -2.49374
3    -2.462477                      -2.556205                                                        
4    -1.712807       -1.90628       -1.902953        -1.9023       -1.90225
5    -1.883432                      -1.932924
```

How can I control it and keep the precision of presenting numbers like in the first DataFrame?

Comment: That may just be a representational issue. You should really check the two dataframes and compare their values (for not-NaN cells) whether these are still equal. Just subtract the old and new columns and see what the resulting column values are.

Comment: Note: `df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)` seems the incorrect way to replace NaNs. You're now turning floating point numbers into strings; that would actually explain your problem: the cells in your first frame are floats, the cells in your second dataframe are strings. Replace NaNs by some proper float value, e.g. 0, or 1, or np.inf or whatever you deem most suitable.

Comment: This is a side effect of the `replace` operation, you've changed the dtype to `object` from `float64` (in order to support mixed dtypes) by inserting empty strings. Once you do that you've introduced a new world of pain. Also why do this? What is the problem with `NaN`

Comment: Why aren't you maintaining type consistency? Why not replace NaNs with a float?

Comment: Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: @9769953 that produces the same result

Comment: @EdChum Well, that in combination with filling it with a proper float of course. But `.fillna()` is clear than `.replace()`.

Comment: @EdChum and 9769953 I understood the problem. I've tried to go around and converted DataFrame to string: df = df.astype(str) and then df = df.fillna(" ") or df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True). My logic says that it should work on strings. Is there anything particular special about NaN?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, the reason you lose precision is because when you pop a string into a column of floats, pandas is forced to convert the dtype of that column to `object`. I'll try to elaborate a bit on the point in this answer. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
NaN = np.NaN

rows = [[-3.030889, -3.510211, -3.502291, -3.502357, -3.502817],
        [-3.460590, NaN, -3.584687, NaN, NaN],
        [-2.151932, -2.504276, -2.494087, -2.493053, -2.493741],
        [-2.462477, NaN, -2.556205, NaN, NaN],
        [-1.712807, -1.906281, -1.902953, -1.902297, -1.902253],
        [-1.883432, NaN, -1.932924, NaN, NaN]]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print()

new_df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
print(new_df)
print(new_df.dtypes)
```

This outputs:

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -3.030889 -3.510211 -3.502291 -3.502357 -3.502817
1 -3.460590       NaN -3.584687       NaN       NaN
2 -2.151932 -2.504276 -2.494087 -2.493053 -2.493741
3 -2.462477       NaN -2.556205       NaN       NaN
4 -1.712807 -1.906281 -1.902953 -1.902297 -1.902253
5 -1.883432       NaN -1.932924       NaN       NaN
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
3    float64
4    float64
dtype: object

          0        1         2        3        4
0 -3.030889 -3.51021 -3.502291 -3.50236 -3.50282
1 -3.460590          -3.584687
2 -2.151932 -2.50428 -2.494087 -2.49305 -2.49374
3 -2.462477          -2.556205
4 -1.712807 -1.90628 -1.902953  -1.9023 -1.90225
5 -1.883432          -1.932924
0    float64
1     object
2    float64
3     object
4     object
dtype: object
```

Note that whatever column had a `NaN` replaced by `''` is now of type `object` (columns 1, 3, and 4 in the example above). Not only do you lose precision when converting to object, but you also lose semantics. Your data is no longer all of type `float64`. So if you try to do some operation over the column, it's going to be hard because the column items aren't all of the same type.

If we drop into `pdb` (by calling `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) at the end of the snippet above we can see this easily:

```
(Pdb) df[1].apply(lambda x: x**2)
0    12.321581
1          NaN
2     6.271398
3          NaN
4     3.633907
5          NaN
Name: 1, dtype: float64
(Pdb) new_df[1].apply(lambda x: x**2)
*** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

You probably want to keep everything as `float64`. **The question is, what do you replace the `NaN`s with? And the answer to that is: it depends.** Only you know your data, and what it represents. Here's a couple options (there's infinitely many more):

You can choose to just leave them as `NaN`s, which might be appropriate depending on what you're doing.

```
>>> np.NaN ** 2
nan
>>> np.NaN - 100
nan
>>> np.sqrt(np.NaN)
nan
```

Floating point operations will just do nothing: the data will stay as `NaN`. Some python libs also handle `NaN`s just fine out of the box.

Another option is to replace `NaN`s with some other floating point value. WLOG, let's say you're trying to calculate euclidean distance between your columns, and this distance represents something for your model or represents some value to your problem.

You could replace the `NaN`s with some "far away" value. If your data is on a scale of [-1, 1] (like if it's sinusoidal data), then a good replacement might be -999. It would be a safe bet that -999 would push columns with `NaN` sufficiently far away from other columns w.r.t. euclidean distance. So if you want "punish" columns with `NaN`, then that's what you might do.

OTOH, maybe you want columns with NaNs to just "average" out w.r.t. euclidean distance (so essentially just fill in the NaNs with a sane value in your range). 0 is right in the middle of [-1, 1] so it might be a good choice. This means `NaN`s won't really "punish" or "help" w.r.t. euclidean distance. You could also take an average (or some other form of interpolation) to calculate the missing values. For example, if your column vector was `[0, 1, NaN, .5, NaN, .7]`, you might want to replace that with `[0, 1, .75, .5, .6, .7]` (linear interpolation).

**Only you can decide what an appropriate replacement is.**

When in doubt, just *try* something. It can be difficult to predict how a given replacement will affect outcomes over a large pipeline. If you don't get the results downstream that you expect, then adjust your replacement strategy appropriately and give it another go.

**Every replacement strategy has pros and cons and introduces biases to your downstream models/pipelines: just be aware of what you did and have a good reason to explain odd results and explain what biases you might have introduced.**

You can do a replacement for a `float64` like this (extending the code above):

```
fill_value = 0.0 # Make sure it's a float. Only you can decide what it should be.
float_df = df.fillna(fill_value)
print(float_df)
print(float_df.dtypes)
```

and this outputs (observe precision is maintained):

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -3.030889 -3.510211 -3.502291 -3.502357 -3.502817
1 -3.460590  0.000000 -3.584687  0.000000  0.000000
2 -2.151932 -2.504276 -2.494087 -2.493053 -2.493741
3 -2.462477  0.000000 -2.556205  0.000000  0.000000
4 -1.712807 -1.906281 -1.902953 -1.902297 -1.902253
5 -1.883432  0.000000 -1.932924  0.000000  0.000000
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
3    float64
4    float64
dtype: object
```